# displaying one field from InlineModel horizontally in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

i have field('image_tag') from Inlinemodel that i want to display in one row of Orderdetail model.

```
class SampleImagesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fields = ['image_tag']
    readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
    model = SampleImages
    extra = 0
@admin.register(OrderDetail)
class OrderDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SampleImagesInline]
```

by default these are showing vertically. how to display in one row?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TabularInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline). Try like this:

```
class SampleImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ['image_tag']
    readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
    model = SampleImages
    extra = 0
```

#### Update

I think I misunderstood your problem. IMHO, you should not use the InLineAdmin. Instead, try like this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
...

class OrderDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
     readonly_fields = ['image_tags',]

     def image_tags(self, obj):
         img_html = ""
         for image in obj.image_set.all():  # <-- get related images
            img_html += "<img src={}> ".format(image.image.url)

         same_line_html = '<div class="tabular inline-related last-related">{}</div>'.format(img_html)
         return mark_safe(same_line_html)

    image_tags.description = "Images"
```

Please see here in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) for more information on getting related objects

Comment: i tried but also display vertical.any other solution.

Comment: @Dilshad please see my updated answer. hope it helps

Comment: ` img_html += "<img src={}> ".format(image.url)` instead it should ` img_html += "<img src={}> ".format(image.image.url)`. thanks sir.